# Let $a > 1$ be a real number and $n > 1$ be a positive integer. Prove that $a^n-1 > n\left(a^{\frac{n+1}{2}}-a^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\right)$.

Tags: inequality

> Let $a > 1$ be a real number and $n > 1$ be a positive integer. Prove that $a^n-1 > n\left(a^{\frac{n+1}{2}}-a^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\right)$.

**Attempt**

I did casework on $n$. If $n$ is odd or even we can always factor $a^n-1$, but we can only factor $n\left(a^{\frac{n+1}{2}}-a^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\right)$ if $n$ is odd. Then I am wondering how I can use this information to solve it. I think we can prove it for the odd case this way but I am unsure about the even case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$a-1>0$

By AM-GM,

$1+a+a^2+a^3+....+a^{n-1} > n(a)^{\frac{1+2+3...+n-1}{n}}=na^{\frac{n-1}{2}}$

So, multiplying both sides by $a-1$ gives the desired inequality

Comment: It should be noted that the inequality is strict.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $a^{\frac{n+1}{2}}-a^{\frac{n-1}{2}}=a^{\frac{n-1}{2}}(a-1)$, so the inequality is

$$a^n-1>n a^{\frac{n-1}{2}} (a-1)$$

Since $\frac{a^n-1}{a-1}=a^{n-1}+...+a+1$, in other words we need to show

$$a^{n-1}+...+a+1>na^{\frac{n-1}{2}}$$

Applying AM>GM on $\{a^{n-1},...,a,1\}$, we get

$$\frac{a^{n-1}+...+a+1}{n}>a^{\frac{n-1}{2}}$$

Comment: The geometric mean is $a^{(n-1)/2}$.

Comment: You're right. Edited.